# flutter best practices on initstate()

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I have been reading about initstate but it's not clear to me how to use and if it's the best solution for what I am trying. There might be other best options I am sure, but I am after some best practices.

I have an specific problem within application that performs some social login and other activities. When I start the application I want to validate if the user is logged, then, if the user is logged return the user to initstate (not sure if that's possible) in order to retrieve more information about that user (i.e if that user has any notifications, etc...) within the initstate function.

I am using initstate within the splashscreen function, so I want to retrieve as much information I can (within the 3s splashscreen best practices ) in order to make the rest of the app smoother. But not sure if it's it's the best way to do it

thanks

Comment: It's tough to answer your questions because there are many possibilities in how to do it & also there are many pieces involved in implementing what you described. Initstate is just one type of state management to mange an app or widgets. I'd advise you to follow a tutorial for both "State Management" and "Authentication" to find out what's best for you.. There are a bunch for free on Youtube and also you can find courses on Udemy. Flutter team is offering this course for free as a partnership with its instructor: https://medium.com/flutter/learn-flutter-for-free-c9bc3b898c4d  - I hope it helps

Comment: thanks, yes, that's what I assumed after my investigations. I think I have authentication under control, but I need to get better grasp on the State Management as you pointed out